# How can I set the focus of a browser tab in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

Setfocus() only works on windows, not browser tabs. Any ideas?

Comment: How about to explain what do you want? Or shall we guess?

Comment: It's for an internal webapp that is trying to mimick it's converted client/server counterpart. We want to simulate multiple Oracle forms in browser tabs. I didn't want to state this because of how many web-compliant dingbats would have said "NO THAT IS NOT GOOD FOR THE USER" without having either read it fully or comprehended it.

Answer (score 4):

if you are talking about switching tabs, you cant do it. sorry.

Comment: techincally if you open an alert box on a page that will set focus to that tab... Perhaps I am trying to probe for a solution.

Comment: An alert on a tab will only "blink" the tab or give some visual clue that that tab requires attention.

The only thing I can think of to use is if the user has "open new windows in new tabs" set... then when a popup window is opened.. it actually opens a new tab... and gains the focus... but this is a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

If this is strictly for IE and for an intranet where you have significant control over software versions, etc, you might be able to solve this by making an addon for IE.